# Limit total currency digits in Format()

Tags: delphi

I have a limited 80-mm printer output and I need to squeeze a currency in 3 digits.
E.g.

```
2.345 -> 2.3
50.345 -> 50 or 50.
```

Is it possible with Format()/FormatFloat?

I tried `Format('%s%*f', [CurrencyString, 6 - Length(CurrencyString), Ratio])` but it just puts 2 decimals after the separator.
CurrencyString is three-char long in my case.

Comment: Try Copy(S, 0, 3) where S is your FloatToStr(50.345);

Comment: @BMS: Copy(S, 1, 3).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis,  a string with `50.9` would give a rounding error if a `Copy` is used.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to limit the output by using the width and precision specifiers in `Format()`.

```
uses
  SysUtils,Math;
var
  ratio : Currency;
  s : String;
begin
  ratio := 2.345;
  s := Format('%3.*f',[Math.IfThen((ratio<9.95) and (ratio>=0),1,0),ratio]);
  WriteLn(s);
  ratio := 50.345;
  s := Format('%3.*f',[Math.IfThen((ratio<9.95) and (ratio>=0),1,0),ratio]);
  WriteLn(s);
end.
```

Outputs:

```
2.3
 50
```

`Math.IfThen()` is a function that mimics an `if-then-else` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach:

```
  uses
    SysUtils, Math;

  function CurrencyTo80MM(const ACurrency: currency): string;
  const
    RoundFactor = 100; //As we have 2 significative decimal digits
  var
    Digits: integer;
  begin
    Digits := Length(IntToStr(Trunc(ACurrency)));
    //Taking into account decimal point if it's the last char
    if Digits = 2
      then Inc(Digits);
    Result := Copy(FormatFloat('#.00', RoundTo(ACurrency * RoundFactor, Digits - 1) / RoundFactor), 1, 3);
  end;
```

The core of solution is the use of RoundTo() and the use of a "supersampling" to solve rounding error and take into consideration integer part lenght to output fixed length result.

Tested with values:

```
  2.345 =>  2.3
 50.345 =>  50.
 50.9   =>  51.
  0.123 =>  .12
  0.127 =>  .13
240.1   =>  240
240.6   =>  241
```

This solution has, imho, the advantage of fixed length (always 3) and maximization of visible value (omitting initial zero).